# Calculate price with amount of quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page for employees where they can choose an item from a dropdown and it will automatically input the price of that item for them. Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#price_input').on('change', function() {
    $selection = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('#opt_value').val($selection.val());
    $('#opt_price').val($selection.data('price'));
  });
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="price_input">
  <option value="Coffee" data-price="3.00">Coffee</option>
  <option value="Chips" data-price="0.75">Chips</option>
  <option value="Soda" data-price="2.50">Soda</option>
</select>
<div>Option Value <input type="text" id="opt_value"/></div>
<div>Option Price <input type="text" id="opt_price"/></div>
```

The code works properly, but how would I be able to add a quantity input that defaults to 1 and when it is changed to two, the price doubles, and when it is changed to three the price triples in the "Option Price" input  for example.

Comment: If you haven't used KnockoutJS before I would highly recommend checking it out. It can accomplish what you are trying to do with very little code.

Comment: Where is quantity input?

Comment: tf? so can regular javascript.. why recommend a whole library so he can do one little multiplication problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#price_input').on('change', function() {
    $selection = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('#opt_value').val($selection.val());
    $('#opt_price').val($selection.data('price'));
    $('#quantity_input').on('change', function() {
        $('#opt_price').val($selection.data('price') * $(this).val());
    });
  });
});
</script>

<select id="price_input">
  <option value="Coffee" data-price="3.00">Coffee</option>
  <option value="Chips" data-price="0.75">Chips</option>
  <option value="Soda" data-price="2.50">Soda</option>
</select>
<select id="quantity_input">
  <option value="1" >1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>
<div>Option Value <input type="text" id="opt_value"/></div>
<div>Option Price <input type="text" id="opt_price"/></div>
```

Calculation works on change, as for default values and monitoring both you can figure that part out. on change for the quantity dropdown functions so that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = $("#opt");
var price = $("input#opt_price");
var quantity = $("input#opt_quantity");

var onChangeSelect = function() {
    price.val(select.children(":selected").data('price'));
    quantity.val(1);
}

select.on('change', onChangeSelect);
quantity.on('change', function() {
    price.val(select.children(':selected').data('price') * $(this).val());
});

onChangeSelect();
```

updated

Comment: ya wanna change the shits when any of the shits are changed.. should be more like.. `$('#opt_quantity').add('#price_input').on('change', function() {...});`

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. After inputting the quantity the price remains the same